# jquery document.ready is not firing on page transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons in my UI, button_1 will load page_1.html and button_2 will load page_2.html. On my first click on button_1 page_1.html is getting loaded, document.ready is fired correcly then I clicked on button_2, it's also worked fine(document.ready is fired), now I clicked on button_1( without refreshing) this time document.ready is not fired.

UPDATE:
I have included javascript files in page_2.html, If I removed those files then the problem is solved but I need those js files in page_2.html

Here are the files:

```
    <script src="{% static 'datepicker/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static '../js/bootstrap-select.js' %}"></script>
    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src="{% static '../dojo/dojo.js'' %}"></script>
```

Any problem with these files ?

Comment: Are you able to post some code?  It is quite difficult to say how to fix this without more information about the problem.

Comment: consider sharing related codes.